PrimeNg make automatically Tab change when button is clicked
I'm having issues with PrimeNG and change detection. I can't work directly with the index (Like "open tab on index 4") because the visibility of some tabs changes, which alters the index numbers.
Is there a way to automatically change the tab? I mean that: when you click on cancel, it automatically jumps back to the 'editSequence' tab. The approaches I've tried unfortunately do not work.
I use Angular and PrimeNg 17
tabViewChange(event: any, tabView: TabView) {
  this.headerValue = tabView.tabs[event.index].header;
  if (this.tab != 'editSequence') {
this.tab = this.headerValue;
  }
  console.log('tab', this.tab);

  if (this.tab === 'editSequence') {
this.displayConfirmationDialog = true;
  } else {
this.tab = this.headerValue;
  }
}

onDialogSelected(value: boolean) {
  this.displayConfirmationDialog = false;

  if (!value) {
this.tab = 'editSequence';
  } else {
this.tab = this.headerValue;
this.editBuildingBlock = null;
  }
 this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
}

and the HTML:
<p-tabView styleClass="tabview-custom" #tabView (onChange)="tabViewChange($event, tabView)">
  <!-- Table View -->
  <p-tabPanel header="view" [selected]="tab === 'view'" *ngIf="!onlyCreateSequenceStatus">
//...

  <!-- Edit View -->
  <p-tabPanel header="editSequence" [selected]="tab === 'editSequence'" *ngIf="editBuildingBlock">
   //...
<app-tab-create-pbb-sequence [editBuildingBlock]="editBuildingBlock" style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
</app-tab-create-pbb-sequence>
</p>
  </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>

<p-dialog
  header="Confirmation"
  [(visible)]="displayConfirmationDialog"
  [modal]="true"
  [style]="{ width: '50vw' }"
  [closable]="false"
  [resizable]="false">
  <p>You are currently editing a sequence, unsaved data is lost on exit, continue?</p>
  <p-footer>
<button
type="button"
pButton
label="Cancel"
icon="pi pi-times"
(click)="onDialogSelected(false)"
class="ui-button-text-icon-left"></button>
<button
type="button"
pButton
label="OK"
icon="pi pi-check"
(click)="onDialogSelected(true)"
class="ui-button-text-icon-left"></button>
  </p-footer>
</p-dialog>

Thank you in advance!!
I tried to use the change detection and to change the tab in different ways.
The this.tab itself changes BUT not the view. I want: Be in editSequence and when i want to leave that tab and click on another tab it should open the dialog and when i click cancel it should stay on the editSequence tab. At the moment it goes to the clicked tab, opens the dialog but when i clicked cancel it stays on the clicked tab and doesn't go back to editSequence.
